# Cookieless SiteMap Security Hole?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

We have an ASP.Net Web Site project running in IIS7 using a sitemap for menu navigation that is exhibiting a cookieless behavior that I have not seen before.

When a cookieless user logs into the site they have the expected problems of navigating through links that don't include their session ID and therefore cause them to lose a session context. This part seems to be well understood and although we could handle this manually all users are expected to have cookies enabled for other reasons (small user base here) and providing cookieless support is a low priority.

The more disconcerting behavior which we've now been able to reproduce is that when a user hits the site after an app pool recycle, if that user has cookies disabled, they will receive the expected cookieless URL and behavior but all other cookie-enabled users will now get sitemap created links that include the session ID of that first user. What this means is that cookieless user A logs in, cookie-enabled user B logs in, user B clicks on a link and because that link included the session ID of user A they are now effectively in user A's session and can see their data, etc. This behavior persists until the site is recycled.

The web config has cookieless set to autodetect and the app pool recycle is on the default recycle period of 29 hours.

I'm going to begin looking for odd request handlers and other erroneous custom additions in the solution but a cursory look didn't make me think that we were seeing anything other than the default sitemap behavior.

My questions here are:

- Is this a known bug or something that is already documented?
- Are sitemap resolved links cached somehow?
- I don't see any programmatic manipulation of the sitemap URLS but is there a way to debug into the actual URL generation from the sitemap to see how and why it is including the cookieless session ID in the cookie-enabled responses for other users?

Any suggestions on how to further trace this will be appreciated.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if it was a bug, but I have no source to verify ya or nay. I've had lots of problems with IIS and app pool recycling. My most recent issue was IIS was destroying the local users environment credentials on recycling preventing us from connecting to some servers unless we explicitly specified the username and password of the account that it was already running under....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once we confirmed that this was related to the sitemap links it narrowed our search down and we found this ["FIX: ASP.NET 4 SiteMapProvider URLs Incorrect in Cookieless Mode"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2472263).

> This problem occurs because the URL table for the SiteMapProvider object is built when the navigation controls are first data bound. The URL table is then cached for future use in later requests
>    - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2472263

In our case the behavior we were seeing was related directly to the issue described in the KB article and applying the hotfix fixed the problem.